# Remount of USB drive partition on /boot silently failing after umount

Tags: linux, boot, mount, umount

I set up an openSUSE 42.1 installation where the `/boot` partition is located on a USB flash drive, while everything else is using LVM volumes inside LUKS containers. So far everything seems to work fine. I can umount and remove the flash drive during runtime (reading [articles like this one](https://twopointfouristan.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/pwning-past-whole-disk-encryption/) was the main reason for my setup choice), but I'm unable to remount `/boot` during runtime: it just silently fails.

I've tried both label- and uuid-based fstab definitions (both work fine when rebooting):

```
# /etc/fstab

LABEL=safeboot                                                  /boot                ext3       acl,user_xattr,nofail 1 2
#/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_058F-part2         /boot                ext3       acl,user_xattr,nofail 1 2
```

When trying to mount the drive, everything seems to be fine (I have tried all kinds of mount options, including `-a`, `--target /boot` and more):

```
# mount -v --target /boot
mount: /dev/sde2 ist auf /boot eingehängt.
```

(translation from German: /dev/sde2 is mounted on /boot).

```
# mount -a -v
/boot                    : successfully mounted
/                        : ignoriert (trans: ignored)
/srv                     : bereits eingehängt (trans: already mounted)
/var                     : bereits eingehängt
/home                    : bereits eingehängt
```

Whatever I do: `/boot` remains empty, despite the messages saying everything is fine. The list of mounts (`mount`, `/etc/mtab`, `/proc/mount`) remains boot-free.

Mounting the device to any other path than `/boot` works fine, though. It seems like `/boot` is somehow locked from being remounted.

I'd appreciate any help to further narrow down this strange behavior.

**Update to answer Tom´s questions:**

`findmnt /boot` returns nothing, `findmnt` returns mount tree that contains everything but /boot.

```
# ls -la /boot
insgesamt 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096  3. Mär 18:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096  3. Mär 18:51 ..

# umount /boot
umount: /boot: nicht eingehängt (trans: not mounted)
```

The kernel has been the same for several reboots. Since the USB drive has been in place most of the times it contains a compatible version. I even re-installed the kernel and thus re-wrote initrd by running `zypper install --force kernel-default` some time (and reboots) ago while /boot was still mounted.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the same device mounted just after (re)boot and it is really non-empty though? (i.e. `findmnt /boot`; `ls /boot`; `umount /boot`; `mount /boot`; `findmnt /boot`; `ls /boot`)

Comment: Also, have you been updating the kernel with the flash drive for /boot unmounted and removed? Could be due to kernel/module version breakage.